# Парсинг xml (rss). Загружается старая версия

Tags: php, xml, rss

Хочу достать rss-ленту с помощью simplexml_load_file. Но на выходе получаю новости со старой версии rss (например, за 2013 год).

```
$url = 'http://example.com/rss/';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
var_dump($xml);
```

Еще пробовал через `curl` и `file_get_contents` - результат такой же. 
Пробовал также пройтись валидатором https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator. Он подгружает правильную (актуальную) версию rss.
Подскажите, в чем может быть причина.

UPD. Странно, но попробовал с другого сервера и получил актуальную версию rss.

Comment: Спорю, что дело не в том, как вы читаете xml, а в том, как вы его запрашиваете.

Comment: @Jean-Claude при чем тут валидный или не валидный. человек говорит что у него данные старые приходят.

Comment: значит где-то закешировано. вопросик не прочитал))

Comment: добавьте там к запросу `example.com/rss/?blablabla` и проверьте.

Comment: @teran, попробовал, без изменений.

Comment: магии не бывает. либо у вас url не тот (мб opcache скрипт кэширует, к примеру), либо для вашего ip выдают специально старый контент.